# How do I implement a variadic pattern to forward variable number of arguments to a function in C++11?

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, variadic-functions

In python, I am able to use `*args` to allow a variable number of inputs into a function. For example, the following snippet will print out all arguments passed when f is called:

```
def f(*args):
  for a in args:
    print(a)
```

I would like to be able to implement a pattern like this in C++11 with the following requirements:

The function f will always take in a value of a certain type T and then a variable number of inputs after; this includes, potentially, 0 additional inputs.

The additional inputs are not necessarily of the same type, so using an initializer list won't work.

The function f will be called by another function g which will need to forward the optional arguments to f:

```
T g(const T& x, args...) {
  T output = f(x, args...);
  return output;
};

T f(const T& x, args...) {
  // do some stuff and return an object of type T
};
```

How can I solve this design problem? I have tried variadic templates but I can't seem to make my implementation work correctly (compiles but doesn't link because of rvalue reference issues).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's how you'd write this in C++:

```
template <class... A>
T f(const T &x, A &&... arg)
{
  // do some stuff and return an object of type T
}

template <class... A>
T g(const T &x, A &&... arg)
{
  T output = f(x, std::forward<A>(arg)...);
  return output;
}
```

Note that since templates are involved, the code must be [in a header file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/495021/1782465) to prevent linking issues.